# String error in MainActivity in Android studio

Tags: android, xml

I am having issues with resolving R in Android studio. Here is a screenshot of my error:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the error is with the layout width String in wrap_content.I do not understand why this is an error since xml allows you to assign wrap_content to layout_width

```
http://217.199.187.200/pentaworld.com/content_main.jpg
http://217.199.187.200/pentaworld.com/content_main_2.jpg
```

Comment: Can you include the XML in your post?

Comment: since this error is coming in XML file names content_main, its better you include that file in your post!

Comment: it looks like you have null space after wrap_content make sure it is "wrap_content" not "wrap_content "

Comment: I couldn't post the other 3 links because I don't have enough reputation points yet: so hear are the other 3:

http://217.199.187.200/pentaworld.com/content_main_3.jpg
http://217.199.187.200/pentaworld.com/content_main_4.jpg
http://217.199.187.200/pentaworld.com/content_main_5.jpg

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my error